# how can I get exact JSON representation of an object in Chrome JS console?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

I have an array with 100+ strings. each string object is an url more than 150 chars long.

I want to save that array as JSON and load it elsewhere, however can't find a way to output this array into a JSON.

the problem is Chrome automatically shortening every string object, by inserting an ellipsis into middle of an url.

for example

```
"http://a-long-url.com/-iEUOk5yiK5E/VdPzE0lOpwI/AAAAAAAC4m4/tHsIFlpSHYI/s999999/A%25B8%25B0%25EC%2586%258C%25EB%2585%2584%2528%25ED%2595%2598%2529-000.jpg"
```

becomes

```
"http://a-long-url.com/-iEUOk5yiK5E/VdPzE0lOpwI/AAAAAAAC4m4/tHsIFlpSHYI/s…A%25B8%25B0%25EC%2586%258C%25EB%2585%2584%2528%25ED%2595%2598%2529-000.jpg"
```

(notice the ellipsis after **tHsIFlpSHYI**)

I tried `JSON.stringify`, `console.log` and their combinations however nothing really works.

Comment: Shove your stringify  into a textarea

Comment: for one-off stuff, `document.body.textContent=JSON.stringify(something)` will let you copy it

Comment: there's also `location.href="data:text/plain,"+escape(JSON.stringify(obj));` which is nice because you can download it in-browser instead of copy+paste